# Simple parallel_for_each in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency

I need to parallelise a `for` loop that does quite a lot of processing over thousands of items. I came up with this basic loop that seems to work quite effectively on a small test.

```
template<class T, class C>
void parallel_for_each(std::vector<T>* ts, C callable, uint poolsize = (std::thread::hardware_concurrency()+1)*2) {

    atomic<size_t> index(0);
    std::vector<thread> threads;

    for (uint i = 0; i < poolsize; i++) {
        threads.emplace_back([&]() {    
            while(index < ts->size()) {
                callable(ts->at(index++));
            }
        });
    }
    for (auto&& thread : threads) {
        thread.join();
    }
}

//use like:
std::vector<int> is= { 4,5, 6,7,8,3,2,25,44,34,562,356,235,66,3,45,66};
parallel_for_each(&is, print);
```

Is there any serious problem I've overlooked, or anything else I can improve?

Comment: Creating lots of threads is counterproductive. The cost of creating a thread is actually quite high. The cost of callback would need much larger than the cost of thread creation for this to be worth while. As a rule of thumb the number of threads should be `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()+1` as an upper bound (and probably less (but that depends on the problem)).

Comment: @LokiAstari, I read that a rule of thumb is also to double the number of threads, and experimentally, the +1, *2 was the fastest and lowest number of threads.

Comment: By superimposing the two rules of thumb we can conclude that the optimal `hardware_concurrency` is exactly zero. <_<

Answer (score 4):

If you are not going to create a long running thread pool (and manage the threads over many jobs), then I would let the system do it for you; the `async()` function potentially runs stuff in parallel and manages a thread pool for you.

```
// Not tested.
// You may need to play with it.
template<class T, class C>
void parallel_for_each(std::vector<T>& ts, C callable)
{
    size_t index =;
    std::vector<std::future> results;

    for(auto const& value: ts)
    {
        results.emplace_back(async(callable, value));
    }
    for (auto& result : results)
    {
        result.wait();
    }
}
```

### Other notes

#### Don't pass pointers around.

One of your parameters is:

```
std::vector<T>* ts
          //  ^  Pointer
```

Passing by pointer is very rare in C++ (very common in bad C++ written by old C programmers). The reason for this is there are no ownership semantics associated with the pointer and thus potential for misunderstanding the interface and thus leading to memory leaks.

In C++ we want to very clearly define the ownership of pointers as it is the owner of the pointer (and nobody else) that is responsible for deleting the pointer. The language has introduced smart pointers that allow us to specify ownership so that when the pointer is passed we are explicit in passing ownership with the pointer. In other situations were ownership is not passed we use references.

If I was using your function for the first time I could not tell if I need to dynamically create the vector or not. Is your function going to `delete` the passed pointer? I can't tell from reading the interface because raw pointers have no ownership semantics.

If you change your interface to pass by reference then it works just as well and there will be no confusion. If you want to pass ownership, you need to use smart pointers to indicate the type of ownership that is being transferred.

#### Prefer prefix increment.

```
ts->at(index++)
```

It makes no difference for integer types. But when using other types (including iterators) the default implementation for increment usually makes the prefix version more efficient. So when it makes no difference to your code, prefer the prefix version. This allows the types of your objects to be changed without having to update the code and it will still be the most efficient version.

#### Prefer `operator[]()` to `at()`

If you know that your access to an array will always be in bounds then prefer `operator[]` as it performs no accesses checks and is thus quicker.

Note: throwing an exception that is not caught inside a thread will cause the application to terminate. Throwing an exception inside an async will catch the exception and transfer it to the future object allowing the main thread to detect it.

#### Don't know why you are using r-value reference here

```
for (auto&& thread : threads)
         ^^
```

Don't know what that gives you. Note: an named r-value reference is treated liked an r-value when passed as a parameter (because it is named). You would still need to call `std::move()` on it to make it bind to the r-value reference function.

> Sorry I don't know the X/R/L/V value naming scheme very well yet so I am using an older terminology. Please have a look at appropriate documentation.

Personally I would just use a reference:

```
for (auto& thread : threads)
```

Comment: With async, this post seemed to suggest not using it in a case like this (http://stackoverflow.com/a/25814457/191463).

Comment: I don't see how I can use prefix increment, as then it will skip out the first item (0)?

Comment: @Jonathan. Yep 4 years ago (when those comments were made) when the standard was first introduced and we had not quite worked out how to get it working it was limited. 4 years and a standard revision later. Anyway as I said the above is untested you will need to verify if it is actually better. If it works as expected it will be better than your code if not then it could be worse but more likely as bad as yours. And with future enhancements by usign `async()` your code will improve as your compiler improves with no work from you.

Comment: It says prefer prefix. I can think of a million ways to work around getting the first item with pre increment and changing the code much.

Comment: `auto&&` is a kind of universal reference, so it will be a rvalue reference or a lvale reference (it will bind to anything)

Comment: Ah ok, I thought you meant just use prefix in the place of postfix.

Comment: I just tried using async instead and it was much slower, in some cases slower than doing it serially (trust me the loop body is not trivial), If I use my implementation it's 2.5 times faster than serial, which is quite a big difference for the users (going from 5 seconds to ~2 seconds)

Comment: `auto&&` needs to be paired with `std::forward()` rather than `std::move()`, I think.

Answer (score 3):

Are you aware of the C++17 added parallel features of the algorithms?

```
std::vector<int> is= { 4,5, 6,7,8,3,2,25,44,34,562,356,235,66,3,45,66};
std::for_each(std::execution::par, is.begin(), is.end(), [&](int i) { /*print*/ });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using a lot of threads - are you sure it is needed? Perhaps try and implement a divide and conquer pattern.
Try and have a look at this example :
[parallel_for_each](https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/multithreading-in-c++0x-part-8-futures-and-promises.html)

```
//*************************
//
//parallell for-each version
//*************************
// code recursively divides up the range into smaller and smaller pieces. 
// Obviously an empty range doesn't require anything to happen, and a single-point range just requires calling f on the one and only value. 
// For bigger ranges then an asynchronous task is spawned to handle the first half, and then the second half is handled by a recursive call.
//
template<typename Iterator,typename Func>
void parallel_for_each(Iterator first,Iterator last,Func f)
{
    ptrdiff_t const range_length=last-first;
    if(!range_length)
        return;
    if(range_length==1)
    {
        f(*first);
          return;
    }

    Iterator const mid=first+(range_length/2);

    std::future<void> bgtask = std::async(&parallel_for_each<Iterator,Func>,first,mid,f);
    try
    {
        parallel_for_each(mid,last,f);
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        bgtask.wait();
        throw;
    }
    bgtask.get();   
}
```

Comment: You'll probably want to point out that this requires a *bidirectional* iterator, so may be unsuited when the values are coming from a stream, for example.

Comment: You should explain what makes your answer better than OP's code. The goal of CodeReview is for people to learn from their mistakes and the "give me the code" approach doesn't yield great results

Comment: @IEatBagels yes I could perhaps elaborate more, however above is a suggestion to think about using less amount of threads, and that would make a difference